# Нужно объяснение структуры overload

Tags: c++, структуры, операторы

Есть следующая портянка кода

```
// overloaded
namespace detail {
    template <class... Fs>
    struct overload;

    template <class F>
    struct overload<F> : public F {
        explicit overload(F f) : F(f) {
        }
    };
    template <class F, class... Fs>
    struct overload<F, Fs...>
        : public overload<F>
        , public overload<Fs...> {
        overload(F f, Fs... fs) : overload<F>(f), overload<Fs...>(fs...) {
        }
        using overload<F>::operator();
        using overload<Fs...>::operator();
    };
}  // namespace detail

template <class... F>
auto overloaded(F... f) {
    return detail::overload<F...>(f...);
}
```

на сколько я понял это позволяет отправлять кучу анонимных функций в параметры. но как это работает понять не могу. почему объявляются 3 структуры? зачем нужно **struct overload** и **struct overload<F, Fs...>** если **struct overload<Fs...>** по идее должно это все покрывать. что значит **using overload ::operator()**?
пример использования тут https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/cpp/td_example.cpp#L195

буду рад объяснению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, это какая-то сильно сложная реализация, видимо чтобы поддержать С++14. В более новом С++ можно сделать просто вот так:

```
template <typename ...P>
struct overload : P...
{
    using P::operator()...;
};
// В С++17, а также некоторым старым компиляторам в С++20 нужно еще вот это.
// Иначе это имеет смысл только если хочется поддержать `overload(...)`
// в дополнение к `overload{...}`.
// template <typename ...P> overload(P...) -> overload<P...>;


int main()
{
    overload{[]{}, []{}};
}
```

Но даже если хочется C++14, вариант в вопросе сделан криво - аргументы нужно передавать по forwarding-ссылкам, и добавить `std::forward` в нескольких местах. И непонятно, зачем они наследуются от `overload<F>` вместо `F`.

---

Как работает: и тот и другой вариант - это просто структура, наследующаяся от всех лямбд, которые ей передали.

Зачем нужен `using P::operator()...;` - если его убрать, то попытка вызвать получившийся объект как функцию вызовет ошибку компиляции: компилятор откажется выбирать, какой из унаследованных `operator()` вызывать.

Это то же самое, что:

```
struct A
{
    void foo() {}
};

struct B
{
    void foo(int) {}
};

struct C : A, B
{
    // using A::foo;
    // using B::foo;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.foo(42);
}
```

В C++14 `using` нельзя было применить к нескольким типам сразу, поэтому авторы схитрили: их `overload<A,B,C,D>` не наследуется от всех четырех типов, а от `overload<A>` (который наследуется от `A`; непонятно, почему напрямую не наследоваться от `A`) и от `overload<B,C,D>`.

> почему объявляются 3 структуры?

Это одна структура, и две ее "частичные специализации": для случая с одним шаблонным параметром (`overload<A>` наследуется от `A`), и с 2+ (`overload<A,B,C,D>` наследуется от `overload<A>` и от `overload<B,C,D>`).

Comment: Интереса ради набрал такой код

    auto ffs = overloaded([](int a){std::cout << "1" << std::endl;}, [](double g){std::cout << "2" << std::endl;});
    ffs(1ull);

Ругается, так как не может выбрать какую функцию вызвать. Это понятно.
Вопрос: Как выбрать конкретную перегрузку? Через статик каст, а ещё?

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый С кастом - это `ffs(static_cast<int>(1ull))`? Еще можно взять указатель на член на `operator()` и кастануть его в нужный тип: `(ffs.*static_cast<void(decltype(ffs)::*)(int) const>(&decltype(ffs)::operator()))(1ull);`.

Comment: Жесть. Надо создавать тему с объеснением как вот этот каст робит) Очень уж сильно с++ усложнён в новых стандартах

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый Это не новый стандарт, это старый прикол. Мы берем `&decltype(ffs)::operator()`, который обычно не компилируется на перегруженных функциях. Но компилируется, если сразу кастануть указать в нужный тип, а этот тип - `void (лямбда::*)(int) const` (указатеь на фунцию-член).